# How to keep flexibility between .jpg and .jpeg file extension

Tags: c#, html, image, web, jpeg

I am working on website in C#. I have database in which photos path are stored. But the problem is that stored path is like **.../assets/photo_name.jpg** and My assets folder has photos with extension **photo_name.jpeg** .
So when I fetch photo path from database and put it into `<img>` tag in src then because of that conflict between .jpg and .jpeg I cannot display photo.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT icon FROM  `tbl_vc` WHERE is_current =  'Y' AND chancellor =335";
MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adp.Fill(set);
icon_src  ="<img src='"+icon+"' width='331px' height='381px' /> </figure>";
```

Comment: Hmm..using `Replace(".jpg",".jpeg")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file exists

```
bool fileExists = File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/"+ icon));
icon_src = "<img src='" + fileExists ? icon : icon.Replace(".jpg", ".jpeg") + "' width='331px' height='381px' /> </figure>";
```